# When did bricks start to have the LEGO Group text engraved on them?

Tags: history

Here's an example of a part ([17836](https://rebrickable.com/parts/88646)) that shows this text molded on the underside:

[image: 17836 underside photo from Rebrickable]

When did bricks start to have the LEGO Group text engraved on them?

And what was the first set to use these?

Comment: duplicate of [Where and when did the straight block letter LEGO logo appear on brick studs?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1254)?

Comment: Similar question but not a duplicate, this is specifically about when full "LEGO Group" text was first added.

Comment: Do you have examples of parts that have LEGO Group on them?

Comment: I've reopened the question after adding a photo of the text that I believe @BernardVanderBeken is referring to. This doesn't look like a dupe to me if I've understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this text was introduced sometime around 2010.

It's hard to determine a definitive answer here, because not all new parts include this text ([nor even the LEGO logo](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15101)). This is likely often due to space constraints, but there may be other considerations as well.

The 8x16 tile from 2004 does not have this text despite being large enough:

[image: 8x16 Tile]

The 2006 2x3 tile with clips is also missing this text:

[image: 30350]

However, some variants of the 2x4 tile introduced in 2010 do have this:

[image: 2x4 Tile variants]

So it appears to have been added around this time.

The 2x3 tiles introduced in 2016 also have this text.

[image: 2x3 tile]